# does drools drl validation be done for Object rather pojo instances

Tags: java, drools

In most the drools examples i have seen Pojo instance being passed as facts to drools environment, can drools environment take Objects instead of pojo ??

More Info being added as per comments:

```
Object object= new ObjectMapper().readValue(json,
 Class.forName("com.EnrichmentService.EsRootDoc"));
```

Can the above Object instance(object) be provided to drl and would drools on its own downcast Object instance to com.EnrichmentService.Thread72.EsRootDoc instance as it would need to call getter methods which i believe could be called only on a EsRootDoc(a pojo class being created at run time) and not Object instance.

Comment: AFAIK, POJO = plain old Java object

Comment: exactly laune . use case apart from plain old java object for drools drl iterations. thanks

Comment: what kind of "Objects" are you talking about?

Comment: Object pojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Class.forName("com.EnrichmentService.EsRootDoc")); 
can Object instance pojo be provided to drl and would drools with itself downcast Object instance to com.EnrichmentService.Thread72.EsRootDoc instance as it would need to call getter methods which i believe could be called only on a EsRootDoc(a pojo class being created at run time) and not Object instance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely. Drools checks the actual class and interface hierarchy of the facts provided.

For instance, if one has a rule:

```
rule X
when
    Person()
then
    ...
```

The following two code snippets would provide identical results:

```
Person p = new Person();
ksession.insert(p);
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

---

```
Object p = new Person(); 
ksession.insert(p);
ksession.fireAllRules();
```